# Web Service dynamically using HttpWebRequest Unsupported Media Type

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, system.net.httpwebrequest

```
public void processVoucher()
{
    try
    {
        string url = "http://192.168.xxx.xx:xxxx/context-root-xxxxxxxx/AccountsPayableManagerPort?WSDL/processVoucher"; 
        StreamReader str = new StreamReader(@"F:\IntelliChief integration to JD Edwards for AP Invoice entry\processVoucher_input_payload.xml");
        string ipParameter = str.ReadToEnd();

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        req.ContentType = "application/xml";
        req.KeepAlive = true;
        req.Timeout = 30000;
        req.Accept = "application/xml";//"text/xml";
        req.Headers.Clear();
        req.Method = "POST";
        Encoding encode = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");


        using (Stream stm = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
            {
                stmw.Write(ipParameter);
            }
        }

        var response = req.GetResponse(); // here i am getting Unsupported Media Type issue
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader strReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, encode, true);
        string result = strReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Error Message:" + ex.Message);
        throw;
    }

}
```

I got requirement of consuming web service, display the result, i am trying to consume web service by using HttpWebRequest  class. I running exception in req.GetResponse() any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't clear the headers, that's probably what the issue is.

Comment: ok i try once...

Comment: Hi Mark, i tried running the code  by commenting the line  req.Headers.Clear(), but still it is throwing the same error only

Comment: when i changed the  req.ContentType  value to  "text/xml" and req.Accept  value to "text/xml"  it is now throwing  (500) Internal Server Error.

Comment: Use a sniffer like fiddler or wireshark.  Capture good connection using a IE and then compare results with httpWebRequest.

Comment: @ jdweng ,i tried with fiddler, i am getting replay result 200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public void processVoucher()
        {

```
        string soap = null;

        try
        {
            StreamReader str = new StreamReader(@"F:\xxx\some.xml");
            soap = str.ReadToEnd();
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.xxx.xx:xxxx/bla-bla-bla/AccountsPayableManagerPort?WSDL");
            req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"UTF-8\"";
            req.Accept = "text/xml";
            req.Method = "POST";

            using (Stream stm = req.GetRequestStream())
            {
                using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
                {
                    stmw.Write(soap);
                }
            }


            using (WebResponse response = req.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }
```

Finally i found solution to the issue, above is the working code. After i changed  **req.ContentType = "application/xml";  to req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"UTF-8\""; , req.Accept = "application/xml";  to req.Accept = "text/xml";** **and i removed req.Headers.Clear();**  my code started working thanks all for your support...